# Select all div siblings by using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I have an html file which has a structure like the following:

```
<div>
</div

<div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
<div>

<div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to select all the siblings div without selecting nested div in the third and fourth block. If I use `find_all()` I get all the divs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find *direct* children of the parent element:

```
soup.select('body > div')
```

to get all `div` elements under the top-level `body` tag.

You could also find the *first* `div`, then grab all matching siblings with [`Element.find_next_siblings()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-siblings-and-previous-siblings):

```
first_div = soup.find('div')
all_divs = [first_div] + first_div.find_next_siblings('div')
```

Or you could use the [`element.children` generator](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) and filter those:

```
all_divs = (elem for elem in top_level.children if getattr(elem, 'name', None) == 'div')
```

where `top_level` is the element containing these `div` elements directly.