# Scraping a DIV then grabbing all <a> in the siblings of that DIV

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

What I'm trying to do is take the current date and store into a variable, then use that variable to find the date in a DIV. Once it locates that DIV, I want it to grab all the `<a ref>` links within the sub (siblings) DIVs.

```
import re, time
from urllib2 import urlopen as uReq
import datetime as dt

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'www.domainname.com'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

date = dt.datetime.today().strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
page_soup = soup(page_html, "lxml") 

### I feel like I'm missing something here!
### Need to add variable (date) to find DIV (i.e. 2017-10-21)
### Add H REF links from all sub DIVs within the variable (date). which I believe would use the code below?

links = page_soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'gameLinks'})
for div in links:
    link = div.find('a')['href']
    if "ufc" in link:  
        print """<a href="{link}">{link}</a><br>""".format(link=link)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select all div siblings by using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826883/select-all-div-siblings-by-using-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the names of each module makes your code very difficult to read, but aside from that here is the typical convention for finding links within a div (or wherever):

```
links = []

for div in page_soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'gameLinks'}:
    if 'some_date' in div.text:
        for a in div.find_all('a'):
            if 'ufc' in a['href']:
                links.append(a['href'])
                print(a['href'])
```

Comment: I understand, however, I'm trying to find a div with a certain text like `<div class="var2">2017-10-21</div>` then tell the script to grab all `<a href>` tags in the sub divs of `2017-10-21`.

Comment: The divs should be named in a consistent way - check the source code out to find it. Just put the identifier in `attrs`.

Comment: If the div you're looking for has that specific date in it, you can just filter it with an if statement: `if '2017-10-21' in div.text:`

Comment: Where would that go in the code above? - thanks evan

Comment: what about my old method of printing the links? So far this isn't working for me. :(

Comment: I've tried your code and no results.. trying to find this `<div class="panel-heading">2017-10-21</div>` then pull the `<h ref>` links from underneath div.text `2017-10-21`

Comment: At least update you post with a significant amount of html elements to get more accurate solution.

Comment: @Shahin the website is https://www.vipbox.nu/sports/ufc.html and trying to grab the links from the date of 2017-10-21.

Comment: The best way for you to get the desired links is perform a search using `league` instead of `date`.